# puppet script for ibm websphere mq

Tags: puppet, ibm-mq

Just started learning puppet and gone through some modules in forge,puppetlabs.com. Is there a module available to install IBM Websphere MQ.

Here are the steps I followed to install IBM Websphere MQ using Puppet.

Prerequisite:

Install steps
1. gunzip the file
2. untar the file to temp directory
3. ensure rpm package is installed
4. Accept license 
5. Run the RPMs 
6. Set up installation as primary.

Step1:

```
  exec { 'gunzip_ibmmq':  
    unless     => "test -f   ${ibmwebspheremq::ibmmq_install_temp}/${ibmwebspheremq::ibmmq_archive_tar}",  
    cwd        => "${ibmwebspheremq::ibmmq_install_temp}",  
    path       =>  [ "/usr/bin", "/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/sbin" ] ,  
    command    => "gunzip ${ibmwebspheremq::ibmmq_install_temp}/${ibmwebspheremq::ibmmq_archive_gz}",  
    logoutput  => true,  
  }
```

Step2:

```
  exec { 'untar_ibmmq':  
    cwd        => "${ibmwebspheremq::ibmmq_install_temp}",  
    path       =>  [ "/usr/bin", "/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/sbin" ] ,  
    command    => "tar -xvf ${ibmwebspheremq::ibmmq_install_temp}/${ibmwebspheremq::ibmmq_archive_tar}",  
    logoutput  => true,  
  }
```

Step3:

```
$admin_packages = ['rpm']
# Ensure required Package is installed
package  { $admin_packages:
  ensure => 'installed',
}
```

Step4:
Accept license

```
 exec { 'acceptlicense_ibmmq':
    cwd        => "${ibmwebspheremq::ibmmq_install_temp}/server",
    path       =>  [ "/usr/bin", "/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/sbin" ] ,
    command    => "${ibmwebspheremq::ibmmq_install_temp}/server/mqlicense.sh -accept",
    #creates    => "${ibmwebspheremq::ibmmq_install_rpm}",
    logoutput  => true,
 }
```

Step5:

```
 exec { 'install_ibmmq':
    cwd        => "${ibmwebspheremq::ibmmq_install_temp}/server",
    path       =>  [ "/usr/bin", "/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/sbin" ] ,
    command    => "rpm --prefix ${ibmwebspheremq::ibmmq_install_root} -ivh ${ibmwebspheremq::ibmmq_install_temp}/server/MQSeries*.rpm",
    #command    => "rpm -ivh MQSeries*.rpm",
    logoutput  => true,
 }
```

Questions I have now since I figured out the process.

1. Accept license steps from IBM is interactive, it forces you to enter 1 , how to you handle this in puppet so install can continue. Could not progress to next step bypassing this unless we manually accept the license. Is there a workaround to continue installing without this step and automate.
2. Is there a puppet module to install IBM JDK.
3. Step5: The way I installed RPMs is by running everything in a single command. (MQSeries*.rpm). Is it required to run one module at a time and in a particular order. Can this run in any order.

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure how much you learned puppet. But best place to start learning is by using puppet VM and quick start guide from here. https://learn.puppetlabs.com

Comment: OK . Here is what I figured out so far on installing IBM Websphere MQ.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a pretty old question, but you can now use the [mq_install](https://forge.puppet.com/enterprisemodules/mq_install)  module for installation. and the [mq_config](https://forge.puppet.com/enterprisemodules/mq_config) when configuring you MQ environment with puppet.

Answer (score 1):

Answers to two of your numbered questions:

1. You can accept the license using `mqlicense.sh -accept` as you did in the example, the response is `Agreement accepted:  Proceed with install.`.  This does not prompt for any response.  This is documented in the IBM Knowledge Center under the [Installing an IBM MQ client on Linux](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q009010_.htm) topic.

   > If want to accept the license without it being displayed, you can run the mqlicense.sh script with the -accept option.
   >
   > ```
   > ./mqlicense.sh -accept
   > ```
   >
   > You must accept the license agreement before you can proceed with the installation.
2. You can specify all the rpms you require in a single rpm command or using a wildcard as you have in the example above as long as you are not missing any prerequisite rpms.

Comment: I know this is a older question, but thought I could add some value for anyone looking for a similar answers by answer two portions of the question that are not puppet specific.